# Can people take advantage of the Stack Overflow bounty option?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I haven't used the bounty system before, but I understand that people place part of their rep points on to a question that has not been answered yet. But I believe that for the points to be given, the OP must give the answer the tick. If this is so, can people not just ask a question, place a bounty on to it and get the correct answer; but not give the answer the tick. Thus keeping their points. Isn't this a flaw in the system, or is this intentional?

Comment: Read the linked faq and all your doubts will be explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points for a bounty are **immediately deducted** from the user when the bounty is placed, therefore there is no advantage to the user who set the bounty by not selecting an answer to award the reputation to. Regardless of whether the user selects an answer to award the bounty, whether (half) the bounty is automatically awarded by Community, or whether the bounty is never awarded, the bounty cost is still deducted from the user.